I want to find the VSE text strip code in Blender's Source code
I want to see and edit the source code of Blender's Video Sequence editor text strip.
based on what I have searched online, it's not in

/source/blender/sequencer
/source/blender/editors/space_sequencer

Any help?
https://github.com/blender/blender

This Q&A site is to help with questions about using Blender and its built-in addons. There are no Blender developers here, nor does anyone here work for or have any association with the Blender Foundation so questions about Blender's internal source code are off-topic here.

is that what you are looking for? blender/source/blender/editors/space_sequencer
/sequencer_edit.cc

Its a start, thanks.
